# Identify the correct code of an SMD transistor used to switch a relay coil

Tags: transistors, switches, relay, identification, surface-mount

I have a problem with identifying an SMD component that I'm sure is burned and has to be replaced.

It should be a transistor used to switch the 24 V coil of a [J01A-24-F relay](https://www.tme.eu/en/details/jq1a-24v-f/miniature-electromagnetic-relays/panasonic/).

Input at the supposed base pin (it could also be a MOSFET, so the gate) is 0/5 V coming from a PIC18F452. The coil is inserted on the collector side. The emitter is at ground. I noticed that there are no resistors to polarize the transistor, so I suppose the resistors, if any, are internal to the component.

The board controls a gas boiler. The relay opens/closes a water pump on the 230 V side.

Over the component I read "XF" horizontally and "5N" vertically. I thought it could be a transistor like the RN1101F but I'm not sure. Could you please suggest the correct code or an equivalent, (preferably not an SMD to facilitate soldering and purchase)?

I attached a photo.

[image]

Comment: TR = transistor?

Comment: Yes, I edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

RN1106 is a plausible choice. If you can remove a similar one and measure the E-B resistance you'll have a much better idea if it's an exact replacement (should be ~52kΩ in one direction and perhaps lower in the other).

If you want to go with non-SMT you could hack in a [2N4401](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n4401-d.pdf) with a couple resistors (such as series 4.7k and 47k E-B), but make sure you don't compromise safety in any way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXjH49.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>